# Display windows console message when shutting down

Tags: windows, boot, shutdown

I am currently using a dual booted laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

When I shutdown or boot up Ubuntu it displays console messages which are quite informative. But when shutting down Windows it just shows boring spinning dots.

So is there any way to display console messages during the shutdown or boot up process?

Answer (score 0):

You can display the loaded drivers during boot time using msconfig.exe, under the "Boot" tab, enable "OS boot information".

You can also add verbosity at login and shutdown time by editing the registry : under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System, Add a new 32-bit DWORD value named "VerboseStatus" with the value "1".

Comment: Yes, Thanks. It worked. Can't upvote because of less reputations